# how to access footer from all activities in android application

Tags: android, footer

i have footer layout contains 4 button. footer display in all my activities like [image]
now i have 2 questions:

1. as image shows when click on any button then color of button image and the background will be change
2. how to access footer button from  activities,i don't want to do copy paste the same code in all activities.is there another way to do this.

how to do this 2 things

Comment: Why don't you use only one activity with fragments instead?

Comment: you can use bottom navigation menu. follow below link https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0

Comment: You can make an activity as a baseActivity and then inflate footer layout on it and attach it to parent ( in parent layout you have to specify a container for footer ) and then make getter methods for those views you want to access or you can implement methods to change views data. and then make your other activities extend this `BaseActivity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1.
to change the color of the icon:

```
buttonView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.yourColor1));
```

to change the background color:

```
buttonView.setBackgroundTint(ContextCompat.getColor(YourActivity.this, R.color.yourColor2));
```

For 2:
You could implement a basic Activity, where you put your code to handle the footer access. Then you derive all your activities from that basic activity

If you need further instructions for 2. write comment